# Conditional nullable type in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've been loving kotlin so far. But I have a problem, which I don't know how to fix. I have the following code inside a class:

```
val dataClass : KClass<MyDataClass>?
```

The problem is that I need MyDataClass to be nullable. KClass requires a non-null input type. Is it possible to make it so that dataClass is KClass when MyDataClass is non-null and on the other hand null if MyDataClass is also null?

Comment: A KClass describes the definition of a class. What would it mean for its type to be nullable? It doesn't make sense. Maybe you can describe more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, let me try explain this way. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish in an imaginary syntax: val dataClass : if (MyDataClass != null) KClass<MyDataClass> else null.

Comment: That doesn't make sense the way you described it. The name of a class isn't a variable--it can't be null. and you can't use it in an expression like that. The class itself always exists. Can you expand on your example to show what other variables/properties are in play and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you meant to put `if (someOtherVariable != null) KClass<MyDataClass> else null`, then your above syntax is already correct.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean for a class to be null?